# API PUT Request with PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, put

I'm trying to send a PUT request to an API in order to add the values submited in my HTML form to the API.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
function ediprinterMarcacao(){
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $dataMarcacao = trim($_POST["data-marcacao"]);
    $horaMarcacao = trim($_POST["hora-marcacao"]);
    //$dataMarcacao = ($_POST["data-marcacao"]);
    //$horaMarcacao = ($_POST["hora-marcacao"]);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $centro = ucfirst(trim($_POST["centro-inspecoes"]));
    $matricula = trim($_POST["matricula"]);
    $telefone = trim($_POST["telefone"]);
    $tipoInspecao = trim($_POST["tipo-inspecao"]);
    $tipoViatura = trim($_POST["tipo-viatura"]);
    $comentario = trim($_POST["comentario"]);

    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataMarcacao));
    $dataM = str_replace(array('-'), '',$formatDate);
    $horaM = str_replace(array(':'), '',$horaMarcacao);

    if($centro == "Paredes"){
        //$centroID = 0;
        //$tag = 25;
    }
    elseif ($centro == "Braga"){
        //$centroID = 1;
        //$tag = 26;
    }

    if($tipoViatura == "LIGEIRO"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 1;
        //$centroID = 0;
        //$tag = 25;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "PESADO"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 2;
        //$centroID = 1;
        //$tag = 26;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "TRACTOR"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 3;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "REBOQUE"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 6;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "SEMI-REBOQUE"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 7;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "TRACTOR < 3500Kg"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 9;
    }

    if($tipoInspecao == "Inspecção Periódica"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 1;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Reinspecção"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 2;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Insp.p/atrib.nova Matricula"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 3;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Inspecção Extraordinária"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 4;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Inspecção Facultativa"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 5;
    }

    $curl = curl_init();
    $fields = array($dataM, $horaM, $matricula, $name, $email, $telefone, $tipoViatura, $tipoInspecao);
    $teste = http_build_query($fields, null, "/");
    $removeNum = array("0=", "1=", "2=", "3=", "4=", "5=", "6=", "7=");
    $teste1 = str_replace($removeNum, "", $teste);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://edigcia.ediprinter.pt/edigciaappointmentapi/InsertAppointment188/",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $teste1,
            //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Accept: multipart/form-data",
                    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            ),
    ));

    echo $curl;
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $curl;
    echo "<br>";
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}
return ediprinterMarcacao();
}
```

I feel like my curl request is not being done well, since it returns this error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Ea7.png)

I've compared my code with other examples and it looks good, so I need a second opinion on the matter so I can discover what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please share the error message in text form, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: Use Postman, if there everything is working, then do `code > php` and it will provide cUrl request sample

Comment: It's a 404 error, so your API route or API endpoint is not good. Not your code. Maybe the "/" is too much at the end ?

Comment: You don't have the correct endpoint. Consult the API documentation.

Comment: Have you tried passing `$teste1,` as a array format rather then query parameters?

Comment: @Hamham I've tried with "/" and without, works the same way. 

/InsertAppointment{code}/{date}/{hour}/{licensePlate}/{name}/{email}/{phone}/{category}/{motive} this is the API endpoint structure and I've made it soo my variable get sent in that same order, building the endpoint.

Comment: @MominIqbal I've tried with json_encode, but I've made it with http_build_query because I need to build the API my self.

Comment: @El_Vanja I think I have the reight endpoint, it is just bad format I think...

Comment: And have you try to send request to this API without PHP code, but with curl CLI or Postman ?

Comment: @Hamham I've sent on Postman this exact request: https://edigcia.ediprinter.pt/edigciaappointmentapi/InsertAppointment188/20210219/1430/12-XD-43/Teste/teste%40teste.pt/911222333/1/1

In  Postman it works and returns no error.

Comment: Have you tried using Postman's feature to generate the PHP code for you, as @Justinas suggested at the beginning?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, returns this `$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://digcia.ediprinter.pt/edigciaappointmentapi/InsertAppointment188/20210219/1430/12-XD-43/Teste/teste%2540teste.pt/911222333/1/1',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;`

Comment: ...and? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments. I finally managed to get it right. I'm a newbie when it comes to this processes so it took me a while to get it.
I'll also post the working code.

```
function ediprinterMarcacao(){
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $dataMarcacao = trim($_POST["data-marcacao"]);
    $horaMarcacao = trim($_POST["hora-marcacao"]);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $centro = ucfirst(trim($_POST["centro-inspecoes"]));
    $matricula = trim($_POST["matricula"]);
    $telefone = trim($_POST["telefone"]);
    $tipoInspecao = trim($_POST["tipo-inspecao"]);
    $tipoViatura = trim($_POST["tipo-viatura"]);
    $comentario = trim($_POST["comentario"]);

    $formatDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataMarcacao));
    $dataM = str_replace(array('-'), '',$formatDate);
    $horaM = str_replace(array(':'), '',$horaMarcacao);

    if($centro == "Paredes"){
    }
    elseif ($centro == "Braga"){
    }

    if($tipoViatura == "LIGEIRO"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 1;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "PESADO"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 2;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "TRACTOR"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 3;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "REBOQUE"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 6;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "SEMI-REBOQUE"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 7;
    }
    elseif($tipoViatura == "TRACTOR < 3500Kg"){
        $tipoViaturaId = 9;
    }

    if($tipoInspecao == "Inspecção Periódica"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 1;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Reinspecção"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 2;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Insp.p/atrib.nova Matricula"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 3;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Inspecção Extraordinária"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 4;
    }
    elseif($tipoInspecaoId == "Inspecção Facultativa"){
        $tipoInspecaoId = 5;
    }

    $curl = curl_init();

    /*$fields = array(
            'date' => $dataM,
            'hour' => $horaM,
            'licensePlate' => $matricula,
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone' => $telefone,
            'category' => $tipoViatura,
            'motive' => $tipoInspecao
    );*/
    $fields = array($dataM, $horaM, $matricula, $name, $email, $telefone, $tipoViatura, $tipoInspecao);

    //code formats the url in the way it needs to be sent
    $buildURL = http_build_query($fields, null, "/");
    $removeNum = array("0=", "1=", "2=", "3=", "4=", "5=", "6=", "7=");
    $path = str_replace($removeNum, "", $buildURL);

    $url = "https://edigcia.ediprinter.pt/edigciaappointmentapi/InsertAppointment188/" . $path;
    echo $url;
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Content Length: 0",
            ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}
return ediprinterMarcacao();
```

Comment: So what was actually causing issue?

Comment: @Justinas problem was with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, i did not need to use that, I just add to build the request URL before executing curl and set CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Content Length to 0 and it worked.